# What's the name of the data structure that's a set with memory?

Tags: data-structures

Trying to figure out the name of a certain data structure:

It's a set but has the additional property that if you add something, then remove it, you can't add it again.

Comment: Does any such data structure exists? No data structure on top of my mind. But this can be achieved with custom code. Interesting to know if any such DS exists.

Comment: I don't know of any such conventional data structure, but you can easily implement one by having 2 sets, one to store the set's items, and another to store used items that you want to prevent the user from reinserting.